# Want to change multiple dropdown value by selecting a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

First of all, this question seems like a duplicate question, and I am also not arguing over this issue. My problem is I am quite new in JavaScript and jQuery so struggling a lot to fetch the right keyword/solution from sites.

At first about the data structure of the JSON I am using. I am just giving a slice, full you will get in the example.

```
data = {
  "0001_Summer": {
    "param": [
      "row_heat_0",
      "row_heat_1",
      "row_heat_2",
      "row_heat_3",
      "row_heat_4",
      "row_heat_5",
      "row_heat_6",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "All"
    ]
  }
}
```

My requirements:
I have three dropdown(With respect to `select` tag they are `device_n`, `name_n`, `value_n`.) menus where I want two things.
1/ If I select a vaue from `device_n` (eg: `0001_Summer`) then automatically in the 2nd and 3rd dropdown only it's(0001_Summer's) corresponding values will be shown. I have set for all 3 select tag same `value` attribute. Right now, it is only working for `name_n` dropdown and the solution I have taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571044/10634362). I have tried to extend the code for my 3rd dropdown menu but failed.
2/ After selecting any value from the `device_n` if I select any value from `name_n` dropdown then it's corresponding value will be shown in `value_n` dropdown. I have set a attribute `value_1` for `name_n` and `value_n` `select` tag. Each value of `value_1` is unique for the option of `name_n` and `value_n`.

**[A working Fiddle link is give here. IF you uncomment line 119 and 124 from JS part then the problem will arise that I have mentioned in point number 1](https://jsfiddle.net/atifkarim/g14kcrut/49/)**.
As I have told before that this problem I have found quite a lot in SO but in most cases I have found for 2 dropdown. One I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246653/10634362) for 3 dropdown but cannot stitch it with my case.

```js
data = {
  "0001_Summer": {
    "param": [
      "row_heat_0",
      "row_heat_1",
      "row_heat_2",
      "row_heat_3",
      "row_heat_4",
      "row_heat_5",
      "row_heat_6",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0002_Winter": {
    "param": [
      "row_cloud_0",
      "row_cloud_1",
      "row_cloud_2",
      "row_cloud_3",
      "row_cloud_4",
      "row_cloud_5",
      "row_cloud_6",
      "row_cloud_7",
      "row_cloud_8",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "value_07",
      "value_08",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0003_Spring": {
    "param": [
      "row_color_0",
      "row_color_1",
      "row_color_2",
      "row_color_3",
      "row_color_4",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0004_Autumn": {
    "param": [
      "dev_x_0",
      "dev_x_1",
      "dev_x_2",
      "dev_x_3",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "All"
    ]
  }
}


function make_option_1(data, select, value, value_1 = null) {
    option = $("<option>")
        .attr({
            text: data,
            value: value,
            value_1: value_1
        }).html(data);
    select.append(option);
}

function make_dropdown_1(data) {
    var select_device = document.getElementById("device_n");
    var select_name = document.getElementById("name_n");
    var select_value = document.getElementById("value_n");

    var jqr_select_device = $(select_device);
    var jqr_select_name = $(select_name);
    var jqr_select_value = $(select_value);

    for (let a in data) {
        make_option_1(a, jqr_select_device, a);
        for (let b = 0; b < Object.keys(data[a]["param"]).length; b++) {
            make_option_1(data[a]["param"][b], jqr_select_name, a, b);
            make_option_1(data[a]["value"][b], jqr_select_value, a, b);
        }
    }
}

$("#device_n").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the device_n*/
    $(this).data('options', $('#name_n option').clone());
    /* $(this).data('options', $('#value_n option').clone()); */
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#name_n').html(options);
  /* $('#value_n').html(options); */
});

make_dropdown_1(data);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>JSON Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body" style="margin-top: 0">
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
      <label for="combination">make combination:</label>
      <select name="device_n" id="device_n"></select>
      <select name="name_n" id="name_n"></select>
      <select name="value_n" id="value_n"></select>
  </div> 
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have all options with you so no need to generate them again .You can simply first hide all options whenever any select-box value is change and then show options where value  matches using `.show()` and then you can set first option as selected using `prop("selected",true)`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
data = {
  "0001_Summer": {
    "param": [
      "row_heat_0",
      "row_heat_1",
      "row_heat_2",
      "row_heat_3",
      "row_heat_4",
      "row_heat_5",
      "row_heat_6",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0002_Winter": {
    "param": [
      "row_cloud_0",
      "row_cloud_1",
      "row_cloud_2",
      "row_cloud_3",
      "row_cloud_4",
      "row_cloud_5",
      "row_cloud_6",
      "row_cloud_7",
      "row_cloud_8",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "value_07",
      "value_08",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0003_Spring": {
    "param": [
      "row_color_0",
      "row_color_1",
      "row_color_2",
      "row_color_3",
      "row_color_4",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0004_Autumn": {
    "param": [
      "dev_x_0",
      "dev_x_1",
      "dev_x_2",
      "dev_x_3",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "All"
    ]
  }
}


function make_option_1(data, select, value, value_1 = null) {
  option = $("<option>")
    .attr({
      text: data,
      value: value,
      value_1: value_1
    }).html(data);
  select.append(option);
}

function make_dropdown_1(data) {
  var select_device = document.getElementById("device_n");
  var select_name = document.getElementById("name_n");
  var select_value = document.getElementById("value_n");

  var jqr_select_device = $(select_device);
  var jqr_select_name = $(select_name);
  var jqr_select_value = $(select_value);

  for (let a in data) {
    make_option_1(a, jqr_select_device, a);
    for (let b = 0; b < Object.keys(data[a]["param"]).length; b++) {
      make_option_1(data[a]["param"][b], jqr_select_name, a, b);
      make_option_1(data[a]["value"][b], jqr_select_value, a, b);
    }
  }
  $("#device_n").trigger('change') //call second select
}

$("#device_n").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  $("#name_n option").hide() //hide all options
  $("#name_n option[value='" + id + "']").show(); //show options where value matches
  $("#name_n option[value_1=0][value='" + id + "']").prop('selected', true); //set first value selected
  $("#name_n").trigger('change') //call other select
});

$("#name_n").change(function() {
  var values = $("#device_n").val();
  var value_1 = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value_1")
  //same ...as before
  $("#value_n option").hide()
  $("#value_n option[value_1='" + value_1 + "'][value='" + values + "']").show();
  $("#value_n option[value_1='" + value_1 + "'][value='" + values + "']").prop('selected', true);


})
make_dropdown_1(data);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="combination">make combination:</label>
<select name="device_n" id="device_n"></select>
<select name="name_n" id="name_n"></select>
<select name="value_n" id="value_n"></select>
```

Comment: Just awesome. have to learn a lot about different parameters and function calling work in JS and jQuery.  
One question regarding this line `$("#device_n").trigger('change') //call second select`. Should not the `comment` will be `call first select`?